# grunt-usemin: exclude file from minification

Tags: kendo-ui, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-usemin

I use KendoUI library in my project, so it's already minified but incredibly big.
Is it possible to exclude it from being uglified when using grunt-usemin?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue..

Comment: @SabdielRivera I posted a new answer that I hope may help you both. I know it's been a year, but maybe you or someone else find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

In your grunt configuration, use an explanation point to make an exclude.  Place those at the end of your src array.

e.g., add to the end of the src array, add:

```
'!htdocs/js/kendo.all.min.js'
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is it possible to do when using grunt-usemin?

Comment: A little trickier -- you'll need to use the useminPrepare post processor.   See the example at https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin -- in your case, do you want to exclude it from being concatenated too?  If so, remove it from the contact files src array in your post function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your flow for js and use a custom post-processor, which basically consists on adding a `flow` property to your `useminPrepare.options` (follow the [basic structure in usemin README file](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#flow)), but instead of just adding a step (e.g. `'uglify'`), plug a custom post-processor:

```
name: 'uglify',
createConfig: function (context, block) {
    ...
}
```

To customize how it will handle files, copy the `createConfig` from the example file you find most useful (see files in [`grunt-usemin/lib/config/`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/tree/master/lib/config)) and modify it as you need (i.e. excluding the file you want).

I used a custom post-processor to add `ngAnnotate` to the usemin flow for js, just changing `name` to `ngAnnotate` and copying the `createConfig` from uglify).